# Prolog and java

Tags: prolog, arduino-uno, swi-prolog, arduino-ide

I am currently working on a project (Expert System). I've written code in PROLOG which identifies type of Diabetes by asking series of questions.My problem is I need to feed these question to the user through the arduino and I'm not able to add prolog plugins in Arduino IDE,Eclipse or netbeans. I managed to execute code in their respective IDE, for example to run temperature sensor I'm using arduino IDE, and to run Prolog I'm using SWI prolog,but I need to run all these different codes together in a common platform. Can anybody help me with this?

code:

```
:- use_module(library(jpl)).

start :-sleep(0.4),
    write('----------------------------------------------------------------- 
'),nl,
    sleep(0.4),
write('*****************************************************************'),n 
 l,
    sleep(0.2),
    write("###################||| EXPERT SYSTEM 
|||#########################"),nl,
    sleep(0.4),





    write('----------------------------------------------------------------- 
    '),nl,nl,nl,




    interface2.



symptom(Patient,female) :- verify(Patient," Are you a female(y/n) ?").


symptom(Patient,increasedthirst) :- verify(Patient," have a Increased Thirst 
(y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,urgetourinate) :- verify(Patient," have a increase urge to 
urinate (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,appetite) :- verify(Patient," have a Increaded Appetite 
(y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,weightred) :- verify(Patient," have a weight reduction (y/n) 
 ?").

symptom(Patient,overweight) :- verify(Patient," have signs of weight gain 
(y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,vision) :- verify(Patient," have Impaired vision (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,tiredness) :- verify(Patient," have a tiredness (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,impatience) :- verify(Patient," Are you often impatient 
(y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,infection) :- verify(Patient," Are suffering from any 
infection (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,bed) :- verify(Patient," bed wetting (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,fruitbreath) :- verify(Patient," have a fruity breath (y/n) 
?").

symptom(Patient,slowheal) :- verify(Patient," is your wound healing slowly 
(y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,sleep) :- verify(Patient," have sleeplessness (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,trembling) :- verify(Patient," do you tremble sometimes 
(y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,sweating) :- verify(Patient," Do you Sweat (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,weak) :- verify(Patient," have weakness (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,anxiety) :- verify(Patient," have a axiety (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,confuse) :- verify(Patient," have confusion while making 
decisions (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,mood) :- verify(Patient," have mood swings (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,nausea) :- verify(Patient," have nausea (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,vomit) :- verify(Patient," have vomiting (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,dryskin) :- verify(Patient," have dry skin (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,itchy) :- verify(Patient," have itchy skin (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,sense) :- verify(Patient," have tingling sensation (y/n) 
?").

symptom(Patient,gum) :- verify(Patient," have recurring gum infection(y/n) 
?").

symptom(Patient,previouspreg) :- verify(Patient," Have you experience 
pregnancy before(y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,baby) :- verify(Patient," Was your baby weighing over 9 
pounds during previous pregnancy (y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,mycotic) :- verify(Patient," Any signs of vaginal mycotic 
infection(y/n) ?").

symptom(Patient,pressure) :- verify(Patient," have high blood pressure(y/n) 
 ?").










   hypothesis(Patient,type1) :-

   symptom(Patient,increasedthirst),
   symptom(Patient,urgetourinate),
   symptom(Patient,appetite),
   symptom(Patient,weightred),
   symptom(Patient,fruitbreath),
   symptom(Patient,bed),
   symptom(Patient,sleep),
   symptom(Patient,trembling),
   symptom(Patient,sweating),
   symptom(Patient,anxiety),
   symptom(Patient,confuse),
   symptom(Patient,weak),
   symptom(Patient,mood),
   symptom(Patient,nausea),
   symptom(Patient,vomit),
   symptom(Patient,tiredness).

  hypothesis(Patient,type2) :-

  symptom(Patient,increasedthirst),
  symptom(Patient,urgetourinate),
  symptom(Patient,appetite),
  symptom(Patient,overweight),
  symptom(Patient,vision),
  symptom(Patient,tiredness),
  symptom(Patient,impatience),
  symptom(Patient,infection),
  symptom(Patient,slowheal),
  symptom(Patient,sleep),
  symptom(Patient,trembling),
  symptom(Patient,sweating),
  symptom(Patient,anxiety),
  symptom(Patient,confuse),
  symptom(Patient,impatience),
  symptom(Patient,dryskin).

  hypothesis(Patient,prediabetic) :-

  symptom(Patient,increasedthirst),
  symptom(Patient,urgetourinate),
  symptom(Patient,appetite),
  symptom(Patient,overweight),
  symptom(Patient,vision),
  symptom(Patient,itchy),
  symptom(Patient,impatience),
  symptom(Patient,infection),
  symptom(Patient,stress),
  symptom(Patient,sense),
  symptom(Patient,gum).

   hypothesis(Patient,gestationaldiabetes):-
    symptom(Patient,female),
    symptom(Patient,overweight),
    symptom(Patient,previouspreg),
    symptom(Patient,baby),
    symptom(Patient,mycotic),
    symptom(Patient,pressure).







hypothesis(_,"disease. But I'm Sorry, I don't seem to be able to diagnose 
the disease").

response(Reply) :-
    read(Reply),
    write(Reply),nl.

ask(Patient,Question) :-
write(Patient),write(', '),write(Question),
/*read(N),
( (N == yes ; N == y)
  ->
   assert(yes(Question)) ;
   assert(no(Question)), fail),*/

interface(',',Patient,Question),
write('Loading.'),nl,
sleep(1),
/*write('Loading..'),nl,
sleep(1),
write('Loading...'),nl,
sleep(1),*/
nl.

:- dynamic yes/1,no/1.

verify(P,S) :-
(yes(S)
->
true ;
(no(S)
 ->
 fail ;
 ask(P,S))).

  undo :- retract(yes(_)),fail.
  undo :- retract(no(_)),fail.
  undo.


  pt(Patient):-

    hypothesis(Patient,Disease),
    interface3(Patient,', you probably have ',Disease,'.'),
            write(Patient),write(', you probably have 
      '),write(Disease),write('.'),undo,end.


    end :-
    nl,nl,nl,
    sleep(0.7),

    write('**********************************************************'),nl,
    sleep(0.4),
    write("################||| THANK YOU FOR USE ME 
    |||#####################"),nl,
    sleep(0.4),




    write('*********************************************************'),nl.
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: Maybe you could further clarify "not able to add plugins" - are you getting error messages? I think your top-level code would be more useful than the Prolog code.

Comment: Thank you for replying Tomas,No I'm not getting any error message, i just need to know the way I can feed prolog code into arduino, I mean arduino should be able run prolog code.

Comment: well, the proposed system is,arduino will ask several questions about diabetes (for example if the user is gaining weight or if the user has fruity breath and so on), according to the symptom selected system will infer the type of diabetes, this code is a expert system written in prolog programming language,I'm trying to build a hardware for that where arduino is the brain of the system, for now I'm executing code from laptop, but i need to execute through arduino, addition to that arduino will use it's own IDE and arduino supports java programming. I hope you have enough information now.

Comment: You should update the question rather than adding stuff in comments. There is a little button "edit" at the bottom. But it sounds like you can just run SWI on the Arduino. Why do you need Java?